# Scan a subnet range, Python 2.7 port scanner

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I've created a basic Python port scanner which allows me to scan an IP address or hostname, and can specify particular ports, or define a range of ports to scan. My code is as follows:

```
# import modules used in port scanner
import optparse
from socket import *
from threading import *

# connect-scan function, deals with connecting to the host / determining if 
ports are open / closed, takes arguments tgtHost, tgtPort
def connScan(tgtHost, tgtPort):
    try:
        connSkt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        connSkt.connect((tgtHost, tgtPort))
        connSkt.send('\r\n')

        result = connSkt.recv(100)
        # prints result if port is open
        print '[+] ' + str(tgtPort) + '/tcp open'

    except:
        # prints result if port is closed
        print '[-] ' + str(tgtPort) + '/tcp closed'

    finally:
        connSkt.close()

# port-scan function, takes arguments tgtHost, tgtPorts 
def portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts):
    try:
        # tries to get target IP address
        tgtIP = gethostbyname(tgtHost)
    except:
        # if unsuccesful, prints out following result
        print '[-] cannot resolve ' + tgtHost + ': unknown host'
        return

    try:
        # tries to get target address
        tgtName = gethostbyaddr(tgtIP)
        print '\n[+] scan results for: ' + tgtName[0]
    except:
        print '\n[+] scan results for: ' + tgtIP
    # sets default time out to 1
    setdefaulttimeout(1)
    # for every port in tgtPorts
    for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
    # creates thread, target is connScan function, arguments are tgtHost, int(tgtPort)
        t = Thread(target=connScan, args=(tgtHost, int(tgtPort)))
        # starts the thread 
        t.start()

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage %prog -t <target-host> -p <target-port(s)>')
    parser.add_option('-t', dest='tgtHost', type='string', help='specify target host')
    parser.add_option('-p', dest='tgtPort', type='string', help='specify target port(s), seperated by a comma, seperate ranges with a -')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if (options.tgtHost == None) | (options.tgtPort == None):
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)
    else:
        tgtHost = options.tgtHost
        # allows ranges of ports to be used, when seperated by a -
        if '-' in str(options.tgtPort):
            tgtPorts = options.tgtPort.split('-')
            tgtPorts = range(int(tgtPorts[0]),int(tgtPorts[1]))
        else:
            tgtPorts = str(options.tgtPort).split(',')

    portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know how all this code works, but I need to implement a feature that allows me to scan a local subnet of IP address, so if I run the program as (python portscanner.py -t 192.168.1.0 -p 1-50) it will scan all the IPs in the local subnet, namely 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255.

I don't know how to implement this feature, have looked online with no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [built-in `ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html) can help you with this. The linked documentation page includes the following example:

```
>>> net4 = ipaddress.ip_network('192.0.2.0/24')
>>> for x in net4.hosts():
...     print(x)  
192.0.2.1
192.0.2.2
192.0.2.3
192.0.2.4
...
192.0.2.252
192.0.2.253
192.0.2.254
```

I'd strongly suggest you consider using the [CIDR Notation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-ip-addresses-subnets-and-cidr-notation-for-networking#cidr-notation) for IP address ranges as shown, since the library can then deal with the representations directly.

Since from the comments it appears you need an IP address whose last byte is zero to be treated as a `/24` subnet I'd recommend something like this in your `main` function:

```
tgtHost = options.tgtHost
if tgtHost.endswith('.0'):
    hosts = ipaddress.ip_network(tgtHost+'/24')
else:
    hosts = [tgtHost]
...
# port handling stuff
...
for tgtHost in hosts:
    portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)
```

Comment: Okay, this is all very helpful, thanks. When I run my program, it is as follows: python portscanner.py -t <target_ip> -p <ports>, which outputs a list  showing the ports I defined, as either open or closed for that target IP. I need the program to know when I define the target_ip as 192.168.1.0, it is to scan all the IP address within the local subnet, and display whether or not the ports I defined are open / closed for each IP address.

Comment: So take a CIDR block like `192.168.1.0/24` as an argument, and then you can iterate over the defined range as shown. The program has to know the size of the subnet - or do you want to deduce the network size from the IP address alone?

Comment: I need the program to know that when the target IP ends in .0 (eg. 192.168.1.0 / 192.168.34.0) it is to scan the entire range of IP address, from .1 - .255. So in the end, the program will be able to scan either a singular IP address / hostname, or an entire range of IP address, if an address ending in .0 is defined as the target IP

Comment: Okay, I've added in the code section above, when I run it using my VM subnet 10.0.2.0 I get an error come up: ipaddress.AddressValueError: '10.0.2.0/24' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 network. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?

Comment: In Python 3 the argument needs to be a Unicode string. A bytes object will throw the exception you report.If you are using Python 2 you'll have to install the module from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress/2.0) - I haven't investigated that.